# How to make `nc` listen on a port without setting `SO_REUSEPORT`

Tags: port, tcpip, netcat, socat

I want to have a `nc` command listen on a TCP port so I did:

```
nc -lv 8888
```

Then in another console I checked if another program trying to listen on the same port would get an `Address already in use` type of error so I issued the same command again:

```
nc -lv 8888
```

To my surprise the second command also succeeded. Investigating how 2 programs can be listening on the same TCP port, I found that's possible if the listening socket is opened with the option `SO_REUSEPORT`, so I *imagine* `nc` is using it.

How can I make `nc` disallow other programs to use its same port? I'd like it to listen on port 8888 and make sure that's the only program that will be listening on that port.

So far I've been able to do what I want by introducing `socat` along `nc` like this:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:8888,fork TCP:localhost:4444
nc -lv 4444
```

Because `socat` disallows any other program from listening on the same port.

But is it possible to accomplish this with only `nc`?

Comment: Technically it may be `SO_REUSEPORT`. For users not familiar with the concept: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14388706). In Linux it's not bad because "all sockets that want to share the same address and port combination must belong to processes that share the same effective user ID". So in theory you need to pay attention what *you* run. Nonetheless, your question is justified.

Comment: Thanks for that link, I learned a lot! Also updated the question to read `SO_REUSEPORT`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking to one of the netcat source code [netcat.c](https://github.com/wengzuyang/netcat-openbsd/blob/master/netcat.c) in the method `local_listen` :

```
        ret = setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &x, sizeof(x));
        if (ret == -1)
            err(1, NULL);

# if defined(SO_REUSEPORT)
        ret = setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &x, sizeof(x));
        if (ret == -1)
            err(1, NULL);
# endif
```

Then in order to modify the behaviour, you need to modify the code.

However I made a test with netcat-openbsd 1.105-7 that is part of Ubuntu Xenial and it seems built without defining SO_REUSEPORT. As it set SO_REUSEADDR but not the SO_REUSEPORT (under a kernel > 3.9) it works like you expect refusing to run a second intance on same port.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, so maybe here it's compiled with `SO_REUSEPORT`. Bummer there is no config option for turning that option off :( . Thanks for your time!